# Read and manipulate PLY files in open3d

Tags: python

I am trying to plot classified point clouds (.ply format) in a python jupyter notebook with a following script. It opens points with xyz coordinates colored by height, but how do I plot the classes of each point?

```
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(file_path)
print(pcd)
print(np.asarray(pcd.points))
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```